# Django Filter only getting the last item

Tags: django, list, filter

I made the below code where I want to filter with selected id's from checkbox values where the variable is "item" and I also wants to get columns where the variable is "pfast_type".
The issue is that I am only getting the last item.I am not getting the whole list.Where am I doing wrong ?

```
elif pfast_type and item:
object_list = FP.objects.filter(pk__in=[item]).values('FP_Item',pfast_type)
```

Comment: What's type of `item` variable? If it's an array, then `.filter(pk__in=[item])` should be `.filter(pk__in=item)`.

Comment: item values is like 371 372 373 etc.. and there is multiple values.

Comment: On the side node, `item` variable name is misleading, if you have multiple elements, then it should be `items`.

Comment: Does that mean `item` is actually a string or what? What's `type(item)` output?

Comment: You are right :) I named the variable like that but it can also be one variable or multiple variable.I get those values  from selected checkboxes

Comment: Item is a number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172583/discussion-between-victor-miroshnikov-and-lkem-cetinkaya).

Comment: If item is a number, it cannot be multiple values. Is this code actually in a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[After a short investigation in chat, we found out the cause:](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172583/discussion-between-victor-miroshnikov-and-lkem-cetinkaya)

Issue is that `item` variable was resolved via: `request.GET.get("fastedit")`. Original intention was to pass *multiple* values to `fastedit` query parameter. However, `request.GET.get` returns only last one.

In order to fix the issue we need to use `request.GET.getlist("fastedit")` and pass resolved list directly to `filter(pk__in=item)`,  without wrapping in an extra list as in original code `filter(pk__in=[item])`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is in `item`, but `[item]` is a list of length 1. So `pk__in=[item]` can only match one primary key, if any.

There there can only be zero or one FP objects that match the filter, and they are all returned.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but as far as I know item is a list if you use with  [] like this.  So item basically has values like 371,372,373 etc...

Comment: It can also be used like this      # Get blogs entries with id 1, 4 and 7
>>> Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,4,7])   according to the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: But [1,4,7] is not the same as ["1,4,7"]. What kind of object is `item`? A string?

Comment: true I get your point it's not a string. A number I need like [370,371,372] – Basically I want to retrieve id's 371   372 and 373